# Is there a way to write _mm256_shldi_epi8(a,b,1) with AVX2? (Shift one bit per 8-bit element between vectors)

Tags: c++, avx, avx2

I need to shift the top bit from each element of `b` into the bottom of corresponding elements of `a`, like [AVX512VBMI2 `_mm256_shldi_epi16/32/64`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VPSHLD) with a count of `1`.

Does someone know a way to shift this way?

Example:

```
__m256i x = { 11001100, 00110011, 11001100, 00110011,... x16 }
__m256i y = { 10111100, 10001011, 11000010, 01100111,... x16 }
__m256i res = _mm256_shldi_epi16(x,y);
```

Then res contains:

`10011001`, `01100111`, `10011001`, `01100110`, ...x16

(editor's note: the question previously described this as `_mm256_sllv_epi8`.  `sllv` is a variable-count shift where the count for each element comes from the corresponding element in the other source, and is nothing like a double-shift.)

Comment: there's a workaround for the [shift by one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35002937/995714) case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the task is to shift bytes of `a` left by 1, while shifting in the top bit from the corresponding byte in `b`, like a tiny funnel shift with a fixed distance of 1. The shift left can be done with a byte addition, then copy that bit from `b`:

```
__m256i funnel_left1_epi8(__m256i a, __m256i b) {
    __m256i a2 = _mm256_add_epi8(a, a);
    __m256i bit_from_b = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi16(b, 7), _mm256_set1_epi8(1));
    return _mm256_or_si256(a2, bit_from_b);
}
```